# Unable to copy files using FileUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I am trying to copy the files from one destination to another. I am unable to understand why the error occurs. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class FileSearch {

    public void findFiles(File root) throws IOException {

        File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            String iName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && iName.endsWith(".tif")) {
                long fileSize = listOfFiles[i].length();

                long sizeToKb = fileSize/1024;

                File copyDest = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\ZipFiles");

                if (fileSize <= 600000) {
                    System.out.println("|" + listOfFiles[i].getName().toString() + " | Size: " + sizeToKb+" KB");
                    FileUtils.copyFile(listOfFiles[i], copyDest);
                }

            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(listOfFiles[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Destination 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\ZipFiles' exists but is a directory`

Comment: ZipFiles is a directory? Do you want to access all the files in that folder?

Comment: That error message is pretty clear about what the problem is...

Comment: copyFile takes in a File location and a File destination, where File destination is the absolute path of the new File.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava the files in the ZipFIles folder should be accessible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
File srcFile = new File("/path/to/src/file.txt");  // path + filename     
File destDir = new File("/path/to/dest/directory"); // path only
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir);
```

Try `copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir)`, you have to provide the source file absolute path with the file name, and the absolute path to the destination directory.

In addition, make sure you have write permission to copy the file to the destination. I am always on Linux system don't know how to achieve that, similarly you should be have Administrator privilege on Windows or some similar roles which is able to write files.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

Why does the error occur?  [FileUtils.copyFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) is used to copy a file to a new location.  From the documentation:

> This method copies the contents of the specified source file to the specified destination file. The directory holding the destination file is created if it does not exist. If the destination file exists, then this method will overwrite it.

Here, the destination exists, but is not a file; rather it is a directory.  You cannot overwrite a **directory** with the **contents of a file**.